# /etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale

Tags: terminal, zsh, zshrc

Every time I open the terminal in my Mac, I get the error
/etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale .

when I type "printf '%s\n' $path"  i get:

```
/condabin
"/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+
$PATH}";
```

It is possible that I have somehow totally messed up .zshrc and .zprofile in my system. also the .bash_profile dont even exist in my system

here are the content of these two files:

zprofile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATHeval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

zhrc:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/saman/miniforge3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/saman/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/saman/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/saman/miniforge3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

please help me as i am totally helpless and lost not knowing what any of these files do. There may be other threads that somewhat touch on this topic, but they have not messed up their paths the way i did i guess. thank you so much in advance

Comment: As you see by yourself, your `path` is wrong.  Therefore, you have to debug your .zshrc and/or .zprofile line by line.  From your codesnippet, we see for instance that `export PATHeval ....` is non-sense, and I wonder what you wanted to achieve with it.

Comment: export PATHeval ....being non-sense; i can't agree more. But not sure what should be there instead. i doubt I am using homebrew for anything. "conda install pyqt" returns "Exception('No compatible shell found!')". Could this be a result of a problem in those config files. and if yes, how do i fix it please. Thank you so much

Comment: The question is what you **want** to do. Setting up your zsh is fully under your control. You put in what you want to put there, and nothing else. Perhaps it makes sense to just backup your current settings build up a fresh zsh dot-files from scratch.

Comment: Thats is a great advice. I edited it to:

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

and for now it solved my problem. I have sometime ago installed homebrew but did not end up using it. was afraid removing these destroy something as i did not edit this file manually, nor did i know they existed

Comment: The `eval` needs to be a separate statement. If you want to be it in the same line, you have to separate the statements by a semicolon. BTW: If you did not edit the file by yourself, some rogue installation program must have done it automatically. There are several files involved on zsh invication, and you better know (and check) them all.  They are documented in the zsh man-page in the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem the install of Visual Studio Code which added the line:

```
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

to .bash_profile and .zprofile files.

The correct line is:

```
export PATH="$PATH":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

PS: I was misreading the manual instructions from [Visual Studio Code on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)